# How do i create a circle with commands MCCCCZ in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

When i create a circle in inkscape using the circle tool and then click on `object to path` i get the below svg:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06"
   sodipodi:docname="cirlce-path.svg">
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1.7128253;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 140.154,165.16815 A 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 91.010414,214.31174 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 41.866825,165.16815 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 91.010414,116.02456 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 140.154,165.16815 Z"
       id="path956" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see the path command is:-

```
M 140.154,165.16815 A 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 91.010414,214.31174 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 41.866825,165.16815 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 91.010414,116.02456 49.143589,49.143589 0 0 1 140.154,165.16815 Z
```

But what i really want is a path with a command structure of MCCCCZ like below:-

```
<svg
   width="345.70975"
   height="352.91309"
   viewBox="0 0 340 340"
   id="svg8">
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#800080;stroke-width:1.29393971;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 89.289322,89.289322 c 42.392448,-38.369033 104.952908,-35.372751 141.421358,0 39.05243,39.052428 39.05243,102.368928 0,141.421358 -39.05243,39.05243 -102.36893,39.05243 -141.421358,0 -39.05243,-39.05243 -39.052429,-102.36893 0,-141.421358 z"
       id="rect818"
       class="square-path" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Because i can only use the path with a MCCCCZ command structure for a svg animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to convert the arc commands `A` into (approximate) Bézier curvers `C`.

A way I found to do this is to use the node tool, select all nodes, and click for example on the *make selected nodes smooth* icon. This turns arcs into curves.

Comment: still get `m 146.65868,142.48958 c 0,26.97617 -21.86851,48.84468 -48.844685,48.84468 -26.976173,0 -48.844682,-21.86851 -48.84468,-48.84468 -1e-6,-26.97617 21.868507,-48.844678 48.84468,-48.844679 26.976175,-2e-6 48.844685,21.868509 48.844685,48.844679 z` I.E. `MCZ` not `MCCCCZ`

Comment: If you then "Break path at selected nodes", then you get a single `MCMCMCMC` path, but now the segments are no longer joined.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik 'MCZ' is completely equivalent to 'MCCCCZ' because in SVG you can omit a command symbol if the next is the same as the current one. If you really need it explicitly repeated, then manually add a lowercase 'c' between every 3 coordinate pairs after the first 'c'.

Comment: @Xrott thanks that helps :)